# Make another class active while hovering a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to make another class active while hovering another class ?
First class is "sidebarIcon__icon-cat_toys" Second class to become active is "sidebarSecond__content sidebar__6".
Here First class is becoming active but not the other one.

```
<script>
    $(".sidebarIcon__icon-cat_toys").hover( function () {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".sidebarSecond__content sidebar__6").addClass("active");
    }, function (){
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(".sidebarSecond__content sidebar__6").removeClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.sidebarSecond__content.sidebar__6` this if the classes of other element are `sidebarSecond__content` and `sidebar__6`.  in html we add  `class="sidebarSecond__content sidebar__6"`, but in jquery/css selectors, this is how we select those objects `.sidebarSecond__content.sidebar__6`.

*eg.*

```
<div class="foo bar">
```

The above div has two CSS classes `foo` and `bar`. So we will use the selector `$('.foo.bar')` to get the element.

```
<script>
    $(".sidebarIcon__icon-cat_toys").hover( function () {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".sidebarSecond__content.sidebar__6").addClass("active");
    }, function (){
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(".sidebarSecond__content.sidebar__6").removeClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have another question - how to remove class active of another class which came by default?

Comment: @user3697406 removing all classes?

Comment: @user3697406 `$("#item").removeClass();` will remove all classes from the element `#item`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a typo: `.sidebarSecond__content sidebar__6` has a space in the middle, making it a class followed by an element. Shouldn't it be `.sidebarSecond__content_sidebar__6`?